# Queue of requests with shared results in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a service with an Observable which queries an array of objects from a server and then share-replays it until it is updated.

If another service/component needs one or more specific objects it asks the service (by passing the keys of the objects) which returns an Observable with all the matching objects from the Observable above plus optionally all the missing objects which are queried directly from the server.

Now I would like to cache the additionally queried objects to make them available for other services/components which might need them too, without querying them again.

Also the requests could be coming at the same time from different services/components, so I would need a queue in order to avoid querying the same item(s) multiple times.

Also the first Observable could update any time and at the end I should have an array of distinct objects (by keys) with the updated options plus all the additionally queried options so far.

---

This is what I came up with: everytime new objects are requested the request gets concat to all the previous requests, but it seems a bit wrong to me, because I think that with many requests the `missingValuesObservable` is just gonna grow and grow in length.

```ts
    options:Observable<any[]>;
    missingValuesObservable:Observable<any[]>;

    public fetchMissingValues(values: any[]):Observable<any[]>{
        values = values.unique();

        // Shared replay request (if any)
        let requestObservable: Observable<any[]> | undefined | null = undefined;

        // Update the observable chain to include this request
        this.missingValuesObservable = (this.missingValuesObservable ?
            this.missingValuesObservable :
            this.options
        ).pipe(
            concatMap(options => {
                // Create the request only the first time, then just share-replay it
                if(requestObservable === undefined){
                    let missingValues = values.filter(v => !options.find(o => ...));
                    if(missingValues.length > 0){
                        // Load missing values from server
                        requestObservable = this.apiService.request(...).pipe(
                            map(r => r.success && r.data?.items?.length ? r.data.items : []),
                            shareReplay(1)
                        );
                    }
                    else
                        requestObservable = null;
                }

                if(requestObservable)
                    return requestObservable.pipe(
                        map(requestOpts => options.concat(requestOpts).unique(o => ...))
                    );
                else
                    return of(options);
            })
        );

        // Return only the first result, and only the requested values
        return this.missingValuesObservable.pipe(
            first(),
            map(options => values.map(v => options.find(o => ...)))
        );
    }
```

Comment: Are the options interdependent or are the resulting values simply the union of each individual option? Also, if so, can the server API be changed to return it a record of values per key requested instead of an array or in a format where, per returned value, it indicates the associated option it's a part of? (Maybe it already does?)

Comment: They are not interdependent I guess, the resulting values are simply the union of the common loaded options + all the additionally queried ones. The server API could be changed if needed, but I'm not sure how using a record could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle the requests as a queue of jobs, you can introduce an `itemsRequest$` subject to push jobs through then use `concatMap` to process them one at a time.

You could have an explicit subscription in your service that does the work of filtering out ids that you've already fetched, fetching new ones, and adding them to the cache.

The public method that consumers call to get data (`getItems()`) will simply submit the request and return an observable that watches the cache for the relevant items.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ItemStoreService {

  private itemsRequest$ = new Subject<string[]>();

  private item$ = new Subject<Item>();

  private cache$ = this.item$.pipe(
    scan((cache, item) => cache.set(item.id, item), EMPTY_CACHE),
    startWith(EMPTY_CACHE),
    shareReplay(1),
  );

  private requestHandler = this.itemsRequest$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.cache$),
    map(([ids, cache]) => ids.filter(id => !cache.get(id))),
    concatMap(unfetchedIds => unfetchedIds.length
      ? this.itemService.getItems(unfetchedIds)
      : EMPTY
    ),
    tap(items => items.forEach(
      item => this.item$.next(item)
    ))
  ).subscribe();

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.requestHandler.unsubscribe();
  }

  getItems(ids: string[]) {
    this.itemsRequest$.next(ids);
    return combineLatest(ids.map(id => this.getItemFromCache(id)));
  }

  private getItemFromCache(id: string) {
    return this.cache$.pipe(
      map(cache => cache.get(id)),
      filter(item => !!item),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    );
  }

}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75966049-s9cxrr?devtoolsHeight=60&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fitem-store.service.ts)

Comment: Didn't think about handling requests in a subject, cool! One last thing is that your code still does not handle concurrency, the cache for the request should be resolved inside the concatMap, because it should happen after previous requests have completed and cached, I seem to have resolved this, see the [updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75966049-4crh9e?file=src/item-store.service.ts)

Comment: Also in case the requested id(s) could not be found, in your code this would result in a deadlock as the `getItemFromCache` would never complete. This could also be solved by altering the cache to include `undefined` value for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to create a service that provides reactive (observable) access to specified objects. When consumers request a set of objects, any previously fetched objects will be returned from cache while the rest of the objects will be fetched from the server.

I think the cleanest way to achieve this behavior is to have a single observable that all fetched items flow through.  We can then build up the cache based on the emitted items.

A [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects) can be used to push the fetched items through.  We can use the [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) operator to accumulate these entries into a Map, that can be used to easily retrieve and update items.

For the sake of this example, let's just use a generic `Item` interface with two string properties: `id` and `name`.

```js
  private item$ = new Subject<Item>();

  private cache$ = this.item$.pipe(
    scan((cache, item) => cache.set(item.id, item), new Map<string, Item>()),
    startWith(new Map<string, Item>()),
    shareReplay(1),
  );
```

The `cache$` observable defined above will emit the updated cache map whenever our `item$` subject emits

- [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) uses the provided reducer function to emit a value based on the previous emission and the received `item`
- [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) is used to initially emit an empty map before any items are emitted
- [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) causes new subscribers to receive the most recently emitted value upon subscription

To create a method that returns an observable item from the cache based on `id`, we can simply do this:

```js
  private getItemFromCache(id: string) {
    return this.cache$.pipe(
      map(cache => cache.get(id)),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    );
  }
```

The use of [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) is needed because we don't want our derived observable to emit **every time** `cache$` emits, only when the specific item we are interested in changes.

Now it's trivial to create a public service method that returns a requested item;  either from the cache or from the back end if we haven't fetched it already:

```js
  getItem(id: string) {
    return this.getItemFromCache(id).pipe(
      switchMap(cachedItem => cachedItem ? this.getItemFromCache(id) : this.fetchItem(id))
    );
  }
```

Assuming we have some service that handles interacting with the back end to get an item, our `fetchItem()` method would look like this:

```js
  private fetchItem(id: string) {
    return this.itemService.getItem(id).pipe(
      tap(item => this.item$.next(item))
    );
  }
```

Here we simply use the service to get the item and push the fetched item through our `item$` observable by calling its `.next()` method.  Remember, anything that gets pushed through `item$` will end up in our cache!

Now, the last piece of functionality, to create a method returns an array of items with the specified ids, returning items from the cache if they exist and fetching them if they don't.  Well, since the `getItem` already has this functionality built in, we can just use it:

```js
  getItems(ids: string[]) {
    return combineLatest(ids.map(id => this.getItem(id)));
  }
```

Here we simply transform our array of string ids into an array of observables that will emit the associated item.  We pass that array of observables into [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to receive a completely reactive array of our desired items.  If any property of any item is updated, the returned observable will emit.

---

Altogether, the completed service could look like this:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ItemStoreService {

  private item$ = new Subject<Item>();

  private cache$ = this.item$.pipe(
    scan((cache, item) => cache.set(item.id, item), EMPTY_CACHE),
    startWith(EMPTY_CACHE),
    shareReplay(1),
  );

  getItem(id: string) {
    return this.getItemFromCache(id).pipe(
      switchMap(cachedItem => cachedItem ? this.getItemFromCache(id) : this.fetchItem(id))
    );
  }

  getItems(ids: string[]) {
    return combineLatest(ids.map(id => this.getItem(id)));
  }

  private getItemFromCache(id: string) {
    return this.cache$.pipe(
      map(cache => cache.get(id)),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    );
  }

  private fetchItem(id: string) {
    return this.itemService.getItem(id).pipe(
      tap(item => this.item$.next(item))
    );
  }

}
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75966049?devtoolsheight=60&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fitem-store.service.ts) demo you can play around with.

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't know about the scan operator which seems useful (I guess RxJS naming isn't helpful hehe).
The getItems solution does not seem ideal because for N elements I would be making N different requests to the server, but this is easy to solve.

Comment: What your solution is missing (and what I'm mostly interested in) is a queue system: If I request the service the item with id #2 let's say 10 times (cause I have 10 components working independently), I want each request to wait the previous to complete, this way only 1 effective request is made to the server, while the others will be retrieved from the cache. With your solution it looks that the 10 cache requests will all return undefined and 10 requests will be made to the server to fetch the same item.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said the server response could be changed.

If we can change the server response to return the following type...

```js
type APIResponse = {
  success: false,
  error: string
} | {
  success: true,
  data: OptionsPerCategory
}
```

... where ...

```js
type OptionCategory = NonNullable<string>;
type OptionId = number;
type Option = {
  id: OptionId,
  text; string
};
type OptionsPerCategory<C extends OptionCategory = OptionCategory> = Record<C, ReadonlyArray<Option>>;
```

... then we don't need to cache unions per unique category *sets*. Instead, we can cache per category because we received them from the server distinctly.

Because you are worried about collisions, for each category, this code caches an *observable* of options (which replace themselves with an array of options once resolved).

```js
type OptionCategories<C extends OptionCategory> = ReadonlyArray<C>;
type OptionsFromCache<C extends OptionCategory> = {
  cached: Observable<Option>,
  missing: C[]
}; 

class OptionCache {
  private cache: Record<OptionId, ObservableInput<Option>> = {}; 

  getOptions<C extends OptionCategories>(
    categories: C
  ): Observable<Option> {
    const optionsArray: Options[] = [];
    const missing: C[] = [];
    if (categories?.length) {
      categories.forEach(c => {
        const options = this.cache[c];
        if (!options) {
          missing.push(c);
        } else {
          optionsArray.push(options);
        }
      });
    }
    return {
      cached: merge(optionsArray),
      missing
    };
  } 

  /**
   * Given a category and a (pending) OptionsPerCategory feed,
   * create and cache a category specific observable.
   */
  private setOptionsFromOpc(c: OptionCategory, opc$: Observable<OptionsPerCategory>): Observable<Option> {
    o$ = opc$.pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        this.cache[c] = undefined; // clear cache for this category
        throw e;
      }),
      map(opc => opc[c]),
      tap(options => this.cache[c] = options), // replace this cached observable with an array
      mergeAll(),
      share() // don't redo what's piped if subscribed multiple times.
    );
    this.cache[c] = o$; // until replaced, cache this observable
    return o$;
  } 

  setOptions(categories: OptionCategories, opc$: Observable<OptionsPerCategory>): Observable<Option> {
    return from(categories).pipe(
      merge(c => this.setOptionsFromOpc(c, opc$),
    );
  }
}
```

This way, if there is a request received *or pending* then it's considered cached.

I suppose it doesn't *need* to be a separate class but compartmentalization makes things makes things easier to reason through and unit-test.

Now that we have utility class for caching options per category, we can use it.

```js
const optionCache = new OptionCache(); 

function getOptions<
  C extends OptionCategory
>(categories: OptionCategories<C>): Observable<Option> {
  const {cached, missing} = this.optionCache.getOptions(categories);
  const opc$ = missing?.length
    ? this.
apiService.getOptionsPerCategory(missing).pipe(
      map(r => {
        if (r?.success) {
          const items = r?.data?.items;
          if (items) {
            return items;
          }
        }
        return {}; // !success || !r?.data?.items
      })
    )
    : EMPTY;
  return merge(
    cached, // results previously cached
    optionsCache.setOptions(missing, opc$) // split opc$ into observables per category, cache those, and return the merged result
  );
}
```

(Caveat: code not debugged)

Comment: The items/options are requested by their keys and they are all unique so they could be used to cache them. What I tried was using only observables and didn't think of actually caching the results outside of them, which could help probably. But what your answer is missing, like the other one is a queue system to avoid making the same request multiple times, maybe I didn't write it explicitly in the question, so I edited it now.

Comment: Hmmm... How long does a request take to & from the server?

Comment: (continued) From pains I've stuffered, I lean the other way! I had originally piped `catchErrror` within the `switchMap`  so that network surprises are just ignored, then took it out before I posted for fear it was simplistic, confusing, and paranoid!  Do you really have this as a production issue?

Comment: Oh! I get it now! I didn't fully hear that this might be a service being used by multiple components at the same time so what you're looking for is a way to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: Updated. Better?

Comment: An alternative API response could be `{status: boolean, items: {category: string, id: number, text: string}[]}` and then parse it out into a record once you receive it.

Comment: I still don't understand what the category property should be and why would you use that to cache the options/items instead of the id. Anyway I solved my problem, see the accepted answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

A separate answer from my previous...

Unless the number of options is huge, consider making an API call that gets **all** options, and also save them in `sessionStorage`.

Your service object can, when initialized, first look there and, if missing, get all options from the server and in addition to caching the result within the service, also stash it in `sessionStorage` to reduce traffic if the user navigates to a different page and then back.

Unless you have a lot of options, this will probably be more performant because the network will be the bottleneck and getting them all at once will be a much faster experience for the user, plus your code is simpler!

Comment: This solution is not worth it because the options could change plus not all of them are used, so there's no need to query them all and cache